# How to conditionally get a union of keys of all objects in an array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Say I have the following:

```js
const common = {
  "test": "Test",
  "test2": "Test2"
}

const greetings = {
  "hello": "Hello"
}

export const locales = (["en", "nl"] as const);
export type I18nMap = Record<typeof locales[number], {
    common: typeof common;
    greetings: typeof greetings;
}>;
```

I want to be able to select a single key like `"common"` or an array of keys like `["common", "greetings"]`. Based on the selected key(s) I want to be able to select any of the keys of the selected object, I am not sure how to achieve this, below is my attempt

```js
type Namespace = keyof I18nMap[keyof I18nMap];

export function useTranslation<
  T extends Namespace | Namespace[],
  U extends T extends Namespace
    ? keyof I18nMap[keyof I18nMap][Namespace]
    : keyof I18nMap[keyof I18nMap][Namespace][number]
>(namespace: T) {}
```

When the namspace is "common", I expect only `"test" | "test2"` to be available for type U, when I choose an array ["common", "greetings"], I expect a union of `"test" | "test2" | "hello"` for type U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's move the `{common: typeof common; greetings: typeof greetings}` type into an interface so it's easier to work with:

```
interface I18nData {
  common: typeof common;
  greetings: typeof greetings;
}

export type I18nMap = Record<typeof locales[number], I18nData>;

type Namespace = keyof I18nData;
```

`T` should just extend `Namespace` (not `Namespace | Namespace[]`) and the `namespace` parameter should be `T | T[]`. When `namespace` is an array containing different types, TypeScript will infer `T` to be the union of those types.

Then, `U` should extend `keyof I18nData[T]`. However, doing just this doesn't work:

```
export function useTranslation<
  T extends Namespace,
  U extends keyof I18nData[T]
>(namespace: T | T[], key: U) {}
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
useTranslation(['common', 'greetings'], 'test');
```

This is because `T` is `'common' | 'greetings'` and `I18nData[T]` becomes `{test1: string; test2: string} | {hello: string}`. Because there are no common keys between the union types, `keyof I18ndata[T]` becomes `never`.

To fix this, you can use distributive conditional types:

```
export function useTranslation<
  T extends Namespace,
  // For every T, get keyof I18nData[T]
  U extends T extends unknown ? keyof I18nData[T] : never
>(namespace: T | T[], key: U) {}

// Works
useTranslation('common', 'test');
useTranslation('greetings', 'hello');
useTranslation(['common', 'greetings'], 'test');
useTranslation(['common', 'greetings'], 'hello');


// Fails
useTranslation('common', 'hello');
useTranslation('greetings', 'test');
useTranslation(['common'], 'hello');
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKC29wwLwwN4CgYwERQFNpcAuPAFSKlwBps9DoAmUiqlzAXwG5NNRIsAOYAnAgSgBLMEIioM9XAAsCAG1UhWuABJqNuLr0wEAHgAcQI2AOgwNwAIaqi8gBQBtXATC08YVbgAujAOcjZQAJRG0oQiAGYOwAQwAJIAjAAcYAAiDlAOCjgISGBkUACeZgQgcXAgiOC8OKLiUjIQZZXVtS0S0rK8nHymFlYwFVWpmWAAsg5m8gBKBKAiACYAPBPddiCOzhDuYACu8ABGBCKBNFNZufkAfEbbMAByDvBEZonJaADWBHKNVuOTyDiMI0ssDixzAwCkyGOEAI5BEDkgqjyknAG3o5BgpkIYDWcnenwg3ySdBwAFUCSYiSSYPjCd4mbC-mAQAB3MAwAD8MABQNq6TuYPc5GCZDABAAbpdMA9XGAPl8fmR8QAfZnua5CwFkGkRDBDTBIlFojFY8CuADkxXAdpudsYUDtUXNyNR6IgmIRYHtvTasmdMDtKnUIA9vAtPutAY8DvqJTDduD-Qgdv1rqoMa9lt9-uxgfcyYaYDTGfa2ZdkY0+YL8b9NsD5dTdb00c9catLcT6bEfRrLrd+d7RdbScdlZz9e7vCAA)

Comment: Thank you, since these types are generated I changed my script to generate in the above output which does make it easier to use